# How to set parameters of twitterapi to display tweets in uitableview

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, twitter

I want to get the tweets and show in tableview using twitterapi. I implemented all the methods of Twitter framework which are shown below. But I am not able to set the parameters.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
   {

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=twitterapi&count=2"];

NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[parameters setObject:@"6253282" forKey:@"user_id"];
[parameters setObject:@"twitterapi" forKey:@"screen_name"];
[parameters setObject:@"true" forKey:@"include_entities"];
[parameters setObject:@"50" forKey:@"count"];
TWRequest *request = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:url parameters:parameters requestMethod:TWRequestMethodGET];

[request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
    self.dataSource = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];
    
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    
}
 ];

[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

It does not work with `<[parameters setObject:@"" forKey:@""];>` and in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSDictionary *tweet = [self.dataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.textLabel.text = [tweet objectForKey:@"text"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are setting your parameters separately in a dictionary your url must be..

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json"];
```

for more info you can follow [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline).

If you set the parameters both ways, the api uses from the url not the dictionary parameters set while request.

Just change your request url, it will work fine.

Comment: @vishy.. r reffered in your answer that, "As you are setting your parameters separately".. is there any other way to do it without setting the parameters..