# Twitter API- UITableView and display tweets

Tags: iphone, ios

Am using twitter api to pull tweets and display it in UITableView. When the user scrolls i get the next  set of tweets and display the next 10. I also have auto-refresh in the page so that the tableview updates the latest data on the first view. What is the correct way to do the auto-refresh:

1. Say the user has scrolled and loaded the next set of data. If auto-refresh happens should i reload the table view. In this case, all the other set of data that i have scrolled will be replaced as am getting only the first page of tweets. Hope am clear on this.

Need to know what is the best way of doing this in tableview.

This is the flow: 
1. From server i use twitter API to get the first set of tweets, say 10 tweets.This is displayed in a table view. 
2. When i scroll, i request the server for the next 10 tweets and then reload the tableview with that data. 
3. The problem is that i have autorefresh for every 30 seconds for this page which requests the fresh set of 10 tweets. if i reload these 10 tweets, then the tweets that i had loaded when scrolling will be lost as am loading only the latest 10 tweets. Want to know what i should do so that i can prepend/replace the latest tweets.

Comment: I cannot share the code as it has some framework..Hope u r understanding my concern. Pls let me know if you do not understand my question.

Comment: I have same functionality... If user auto-refreshes the page then it will show first 10 tweets.

Comment: When the user scrolls the page, the next 10 tweets are added. The latest tweets are always shown on top. So, when the screen auto refreshes want to append/replace the latest tweets at the top.

Comment: you can sort tweets according to your need...

Comment: can i get some proper response folks

Comment: first get tweets by parsing into the array, then use some sorting methods on array then you will get what you want... Also you can use google for the ready made sorting array Codes !!!

Comment: @user694688 its really hard to answer your question cause you are not providing that much information or code ..  I guess you have done something like this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12854323/how-to-set-parameters-of-twitterapi-to-display-tweets-in-uitableview

Comment: Have added some more info to the question at the top.Pls hlp

Comment: Can anyone provide a proper solution for the above question.